# Combining to tables and sorting by latest latest date

Tags: php, mysqli

I am real beginner to php-mysql and am trying to figure this out.

I have two tables, as shown: a topic table and a conversation table.

I'm trying to merge the tables to:

1) display the titles that belong to a specific category (for example, if category=color, display the titles: 'Color of orange' and 'Color of banana'.)

2) display the date of the last comment made associated with each title (for, example, the latest date for 'Color of orange' is 2009

3) Sort the titles by the latest date - descending

I can manage doing part I, but I'm lost with part 2 and 3. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Image of tables and desired results]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, this code seems to work for me.

```
SELECT title, dateM FROM topic JOIN 
(SELECT topic_id, MAX(date) as dateM FROM conversation GROUP BY topic_id
) AS c
ON c.topic_id=topic.id 
WHERE category=color ORDER by dateM DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is a join:

```
SELECT `topic`.`title`, `conversation`.`year`
FROM `conversation`
INNER JOIN `topic` on `topic`.`ID` = `conversation`.`topic_id`
```

Comment: you should consider the fact the topic may not have replies.

Answer (score -1):

You'll use SELECT CASE, JOIN and subquery to achieve that.

## EDIT

Lets start from begining. As I don't know your table's names I'll write some fake names. You said you have two tables: one for topics and other for replies. You also mentioned some categories but you didn't specified how it works, so I'll write it as a column of topic's table.

## `Table T = Topic's table` + `Table R = Reply's table`

Also consider `registry_date` a TIMESTAMP column where we save the registration date of our rows.

To achieve your order by last change you need to get some info like:

1. Is there an answer (reply)?
2. If so, what's the registration date of
   the latest reply?

You can answer both questions by searching for the last reply.

`SELECT R.topicID, R.registry_date FROM R GROUP BY R.topicID ORDER BY R.registry_date DESC`

That will be your subquery. But as you need it in your ORDER BY query you should JOIN that result with your topic's table.

`SELECT T.title, T.category FROM T LEFT JOIN {subquery} AS Rs ON T.ID=Rs.topicID GROUP BY T.ID`

It's not ordering yet. Please note that I called our subquery result "Rs".
Now we'll use our CASE. Different from what I wrote earlier, instead of doing SELECt CASE I'll try ORDER BY CASE, alright? That's simple.

First lets mount our CASE query.

```
CASE
    WHEN Rs.registry_date IS NULL THEN T.registry_date
    ELSE Rs.registry_date
END
```

Our first conditional checks if there's any answer. If it's empty, we will use the topic's registration date. If it's populated, we will use the reply's registration date. Now we apply that CASE query on our ORDER BY like this:

```
ORDER BY {CASE} DESC
```

As you probably want the last change date info we'll need to get it on our SELECT. You can use your CASE query here too.

```
SELECT T.title, T.category, {CASE} AS `last_change` (...)
```

Then our query ends up like this:

```
SELECT
    T.title,
    T.category,
    CASE
        WHEN Rs.registry_date IS NULL THEN T.registry_date
        ELSE Rs.registry_date
    END AS `last_change`
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        R.topicID,
        R.registry_date
    FROM R
    GROUP BY R.topicID
    ORDER BY R.registry_date DESC
) AS Rs ON Rs.topicID=T.ID
GROUP BY T.ID
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN Rs.registry_date IS NULL THEN T.registry_date
        ELSE Rs.registry_date
    END DESC
```

## PS: you can improve your own "WHERE" statements here.

Just as you asked, for example, `WHERE T.category='color'`

```
SELECT
    T.title,
    T.category,
    CASE
        WHEN Rs.registry_date IS NULL THEN T.registry_date
        ELSE Rs.registry_date
    END AS `last_change`
FROM T
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        R.topicID,
        R.registry_date
    FROM R
    GROUP BY R.topicID
    ORDER BY R.registry_date DESC
) AS Rs ON Rs.topicID=T.ID
WHERE T.category='color'
GROUP BY T.ID
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN Rs.registry_date IS NULL THEN T.registry_date
        ELSE Rs.registry_date
    END DESC
```

Please let me know if something's missing.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand the code.

Comment: i'm late but I'm here now, wait a minute @Sharon99

Comment: I'm not doing his homework, just responding as he should do. @meda

Comment: Which question are you responding too, certainly not that one above

Comment: On that way he can answer both 3 questions. Are you blind? @meda

Comment: seriously what did you smoke, even the OP is confused, just delete this

Comment: We use that code to order forum topics by the last reply, for example. It's the same point

Comment: Kiko, thank you for the code. It's going to take me some time to figure this out, but you pointed me in the right direction: Grouping and subqueries. Thanks for your help.